# ID column in PostgreSQL (Laravel 5.8)

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, database-migration

I'm creating a laravel application that lets users make a blog post.

The Post model looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    // Table Name
    protected $table = 'posts';
    // Primary key
    public $primaryKey = 'id';
    // Timestamps
    public $timestamps = true;
}
```

And this is the migration file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreatePostsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->mediumText('body');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
    * Reverse the migrations.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function down()
    {
       Schema::dropIfExists('posts');
    }
}
```

I'm using a PostgreSQL database and the problem is that `$table->increments('id');` makes the ID column "Integer" type instead of "Serial" which is used in Postgres for this type of field.

This creates the following error when I try to update posts:
`Unique violation: 7 ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "posts_pkey" DETAIL: Key (id)=(1) already exists. (SQL: insert into "posts" ("title", "body", "updated_at", "created_at") values (Post 3, Test test test, 2019-03-06 17:27:37, 2019-03-06 17:27:37) returning "id")`

I need a way to define this field as "serial".

**EDIT:**
My PostsController store function looks like this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required',
        'body' => 'required'
    ]);

    // Create post
    $post = new Post;
    $post->title = $request->input('title');
    $post->body = $request->input('body');
    $post->save();

    return redirect('/posts')->with('success', 'Post created');
}
```

Comment: This says the `increments` generates as `serial`. you must be missing something. https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/tests/Database/DatabasePostgresSchemaGrammarTest.php#L27

Comment: Are you trying to add an ID while saving the model? show us your `$post->save()` controller code or something like that.

Comment: I'm not trying to add an ID. I added controller code to question. Also, you can check Shobi's answer. It helped me get rid of error, column type is still integer instead of serial. Maybe the problem is my postgres verison (9.6)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the `'id'` column is the primary key and you don't need to specify it in the model, maybe that's why it tries to make the column integer.

Try to remove the

```
public $primaryKey = 'id';
```

from the model definition and try to do a fresh migration and run the query.

I'm not sure about this answer but its a bit long for a comment so posting an answer

Comment: This worked, but column type in my database is still integer instead of serial. At least I don't get an error when I create a new post. Thanks for help. I will test this more and accept answer if it works.

Comment: I tested all CRUD functions on my posts, and they work well. ID column in database is still integer instead of serial, but it seems to work, so thanks again.